# Differences between "has started taking", "has been taking", "has taken" and "took"

Tags: difference, meaning, tense, aspect

Can anybody explain the meaning of these sentences?

> 1. He has **started taking** antidepressants.
> 2. He has **been taking** antidepressants.
> 3. He **has taken** antidepressants.
> 4. He **took** antidepressants.

Comment: The fourth one is just plain wrong.

Comment: Read about Tenses. That will help!

Comment: Welcome to ELL. There are a couple of problems with this question. **1)** None of your examples is a complete sentence. *Take* is a **transitive verb**, meaning it requires a Direct Object. **2)** Even if you supply a Direct Object, explaining the full 'meaning' of just one of these forms would require a longer answer than can be given here. Why don't you tell us, in as much detail as possible, what you do and don't understand, and perhaps that will narrow the subject enough for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He **has started** taking antidepressants.

It'll be used in the case when `he` has recently started the process of taking those antidepressants.

> He has **been taking** antidepressants.

It'll be used to signify that a significant time has passed since `he` started taking the antidepressants.

> He **has taken** antidepressants.

This and the first one are similar in context of time-frame. But this will just mean that `he` has taken the antidepressants for a particular time while the first one will mean that `he` either has a habit of taking antidepressants or `he` has been prescribed for it.

> He **took** antidepressants.

Similar to the previous one. The tense here is past, where as in the **has taken** case, it was past-participle.